# TILED : gzip compression not available

Tags: java, base64, gzip, slick2d, tiled

I recently started using Slick2D (java lib for 2D game dev) and I wanted to use TILED to create the maps using tilesets. 
The problem is that Slick requires a map compressed in base 64 with gzip, which is, I think, supposed to be included in TILED [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpQzJ.png).

The problem I have is that my TILED doesn't propose this option as seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ZEw.png).

I tried compression with zlib but Slick doesn't accept the resulting map, so if anyone as an idea, or ever encountered the same issue, your help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The "gzip" compression option was deprecated years ago because it has no advantages over the "zlib" method. "zlib" is more suited for this use-case since it does not include fields for file-related information in its header.

You could make Slick2D support "zlib" compression by using the [InfalterInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) instead of its subclass [GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html), if the latest version of Slick2D doesn't already support it.

Alternatively, you can still select the "Base64 (gzip compressed)" format in Tiled after creating your map, in the Map -> Map Properties... under "Tile Layer Format".